# Using for loop to strip white space and resetting the pointer prior to reading a file

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm and have been very happy so far. However, today I ran into a issue that I can't figure out or explain. The code will prompt the user for an input file. The file is a .txt file that contains lines of words. After the user provides the filename, the program will open it, remove white spaces at the end of the lines and print the contents of the file. (lots_of_words.txt = example)

**INPUT**

```
print(lots_of_words.txt)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Programming is fun and will save the world from errors! ....
```

Here is the part of the code that is causing the confusion:

```
user_input = input('Enter the file name: ')

open_file = open(user_input)

for line in open_file:
    line = line.rstrip()

read_file = open_file.read()

print(read_file)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Now by just removing the for loop with string.rstrip(), the text file prints fine:

**INPUT**

```
user_input = input('Enter the file name: ')

open_file = open(user_input)
                               # Removed for loop 
read_file = open_file.read()

print(read_file)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Programming is fun and will save the world from errors! ....
```

I'm using python 3.4 with Pycharm IDE. I realize that the script completed fine without errors, but why won't it print the final variable? I'm sure this is a simple answer, but I can't figure it out.

Running the same code in Python 2.7, prints fine even with string.rstrip().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with PyCharm.

Your `for` moves the pointer to the end of the file. To use `open_file` again, use `seek(0)`, before printing.

```
open_file = open(user_input)

for line in open_file:
    line = line.rstrip()

open_file.seek(0)
read_file = open_file.read()

print(read_file)
```

Not the most efficient solution though (if efficiency matters in given situation), since you read all the lines twice. You can either store each line after reading it (as suggested in the other answer), or print each line after striping it.

Also, `rstrip()` will remove whitespaces at the end of the string, but not `'\n'`.

---

*Irrelevant*:  You should use `with open() as.. :` instead of `open()` since it closes the file automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over your file object in the for loop will consume it, so there will be nothing left to read, you're simply discarding all lines.

If you want to strip all whitespace from all lines, you could use:

```
user_input = input('Enter the file name: ')   
open_file = open(user_input)

lines = []
for line in open_file:
    lines.append(line.rstrip())

print(''.join(lines))
```

or even shorter:

```
print(''.join(line.rstrip() for line in open_file))
```